# What is this thin-stemmed plant with narrow leaves in an aquaponics bed in my greenhouse?

Tags: identification, indoors, greenhouse, aquaponic

[image]

This plant grew from seed to about 2' high within 3 months. I'm sure it's not done growing. I have no clue what it could be, since I'm in the bad habit of sticking anything that looks like a seed into the soil. It could come from the grocery store fruit or veggie, it could be a seed that I did not label etc. It's inside a greenhouse, growing in an aquaponics bed. I hope it is edible :-)

Comment: Can you tell us where this greenhouse is to help us narrow down possibilities? Please post a picture of the entire plant as well. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Does it have a milky sap?

Comment: Could be a type of [smartweed](https://www.google.com/search?q=smartweed&biw=1280&bih=638&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwx7uyibjLAhUqmIMKHYKQDiIQ_AUIBygB)?

Answer (score 1):

Also looks a bit like a mustard or rocket plant.